# Unable to add content in TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having the TextArea in my HTML page.
It gets enabled and disabled programatically. When it is disabled, I will add some content to it programatically. Later when it is not disabled I am editing content of text box manually.

But after that if I try to add something to it programatically when it is disabled, I am not able to add those content to it.

Has anyone faced such issue. Please, let me know if you have some solution for it.

i am using

```
$("#textNote").attr("disabled","disabled"); ==> disable textArea
 $("#textNote").removeAttr("disabled","disabled"); ==> to enable it again
 $("#textNote").append(data); ==> to add data through Javscript.
```

But is seems that if textarea is enabled, and it I edit it. and then through JS i able trying to add some data to it. it is not able to add it.

Comment: Add some revelant code please :) !

Comment: code i am not able to provide it with proper example. Thus, editing what ever i am doing.Still will try it code some sort of example

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't know what the problem could be this seems to work on:

http://jsfiddle.net/bZpnm/

Adding code would help as the comments say